# Prevent Octal Conversion not working with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

i have this variable, and i am trying to split each number into their own array

`var input  = [[010101], [101101]];`

so i do this, taking into account Octal number

`var firstArr = Array.from(input[0].toString(8))`

But it still throws out `4161` as output

Could anyone suggest what i am doing wrong or what  is wrong?

Comment: If `var input  = [[010101], [101101]];` is in the source code, there's nothing you can do but fix the source code

Comment: `input[0]` is the array `[010101]` not a number.

Comment: Please make me understand, so why is it still outputting 4161 in my code? the radix option isn't working

Comment: Because you are calling `toString` *on an array*, and arrays don't take a radix parameter in the method.

Comment: thank you i understand now, how would i go about it then?

Answer (score 0):

2nd missed 0 to be octal, but if added in definition or code, is that it ?

JSON.stringify is used to reduce useless lines in demo printout.

```js
var input  = [[010101], [101101]];
var firstArr = Array.from(input[0][0].toString(8))
console.log(JSON.stringify(firstArr));
var nd = Array.from(('0'+input[1][0]).toString(8))
console.log(JSON.stringify(nd));
```